# io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.XRRealmModuleMediator

Tags: android, realm

I've tried to add this [plugin](https://github.com/ebanx/swipe-button/) to my project.

Everytime I try to add it, I get this runtime error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.xcify.isap.xrwarehouse.XRWarehouseApp: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.XRRealmModuleMediator
```

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.isap.xrwarehouse"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.1.0'

    compile project(':swipe-button')  //this is the problem library
    compile project(':libs:xrappdb')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have also attached the library [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/eeefd13b84dc2798256b141caf8deab020170828072019/84484f). I've tried to clean the project, restart the Android studio (also using Invalidate and Restart), but none work.

Any idea? Please help.

Thanks,
Sam

### UPDATE

It worked on Android 5 (Marshmallow), but doesn't work on Android Kit Kat. It also doesn't work on my nox emulator which is Android Kit Kat. Any idea why?

Comment: I am not good at Kotlin, but I know some projects with Kotlin encounter similar problem and swipe library uses Kotlin. Can you add this dependency `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'` and add `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'` between android plugin and Realm plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Then for Android 4.4 or lower, you also need to do

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { // <--
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: Hi EpicPandaForce, mate, you are my favorite Panda. You've helped me a lot in the past. Btw, I didn't use the kotlin. I've removed all the dependencies to kotlin. Here is the clean library (just contain swipe-button). https://wetransfer.com/downloads/eeefd13b84dc2798256b141caf8deab020170828072019/84484f

Comment: Hi EpicPandaForce, I did remove Kotlin from "swipe-button" library. They only use kotlin for their "testing app". So I only use "swipe-button" library and I can assure you that there is no kotlin there. I've successfully run my app on Android 5 (Marshmallow). But it doesn't work on Android Kit Kat.

Comment: Oh... man, I went completely off rails with Kotlin -_- this is a multidex issue, I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: EPIC!!! EPIC!!! I love EPIC PANDA!!! It worked!!! Thank you my great Panda. You are truly the most epic panda ever!!!